# Trouble with tabs and translucent statusbar/navigation for android 4.4

Tags: android, statusbar, android-4.4-kitkat

I want to add translucent statusbar and navigation to my app (for kitkat) and on most places it works well.

I have a theme with:

```
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

and in my layouts I have `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`

For normal activities this works fine, but I have two activities that make trouble. -> The content is shown behind the statusbar and my actionbar.

One of them is the PreferenceActivity were I fixed it by adding `findViewById(android.R.id.list).setFitsSystemWindows(true);`

The second is an Activity with `ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS` and there I can't find the right target for the `setFitsSystemWindows(true)` call.

I tried with `findViewById(android.R.id.content)` and `findViewById(android.R.id.tabcontent)`. I also tried to add the xml attribute to the layout of my fragment but no success.

Comment: No answer here but a question. In your preference activity did you make the status bar the same color as your actionbar? I'm trying to figure out how to do this without making the whole PreferenceActivity the same color.

Comment: as i never got a solution to this problem i decided to not change the statusbar at all (for now). so i have no idea how you could achieve this, sorry.

Comment: did you found the solution? please share!

Comment: I found this, hope it helps :
[https://github.com/Takhion/android-extendedactionbar](https://github.com/Takhion/android-extendedactionbar)

Comment: So I ended up using PreferenceFragment and SystemBarTintManager and it works fine. https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint

Comment: Is the android:fitsSystemWindows in your app Theme? Try putting it in there.

Answer (score 2):

Add a 25 dp paddingTop on your toolbar

Comment: nice hack. Don't forget to adjust the height of your toolbar in case you are using ?android:attr/actionBarSize which is 56 dp, so the final height would be 56 + 16dp ==  android:layout_height="72dp"